# How to substring from a certian index to the end in SQL

Tags: sql, string, db2, substr

I want to get the substring from e.g. START=3 to the end of the string.

| Str |
| --- |
| stringExample |
| anotherStringExample |

I need something like this:

```
SUBSTR(str, 3, `**end**`)
```

and the output should be:

| Str |
| --- |
| ringExample |
| otherStringExample |

Comment: I'd try `SUBSTR(str,3)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query

```
select SUBSTR(Str,3,LENGTH(Str)-3+1) as Str;
```

or

```
select SUBSTR(Str,3) as Str;
```

[substr function w3schools link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_substr.asp)